# Reload the data on each visit

Tags: angularjs

I fill a list of data via API interface. For this I call the function `loadData ()` via the view with `ng-init = "loadData ()"` in the controller.

If I now change the view and back again, `loadData ()` should be called again, so that new data should load.

How can I force this? I would like to re-visit the view that the data is recalled.

Comment: `If I now change the view and back again` what does it mean? do you use states? do you kill old controller when go back? please clarify in your question

Comment: i guess your dont want to refresh page if so you have to use ng-model so you can bind your data from $scope with the view